# Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates new angular project, but build forever

Tags: c#, visual-studio, angular

I'm using visual studio 2017, and I want to develop an Angular 2 project. This project is only for front-end pages, services are already built with a web api.

So, I installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates` first, then I executed `dotnet new angular` to create a new angular project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

But when I open it in Visual Studio and tried to run it, it takes forever to build. No error occurs, it just keeps on building. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I watch video here https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103 found out, what i missed is restore and `npm install`.